# Floquet substitution and matrix exponentials

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, substitution

Given
$$
    \dot{y}
    =
    A(t)y,\quad
    A(t)=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 + \frac{\cos t}{2 + \sin t} & 0 \\
    1 & -1
    \end{pmatrix},
    \quad y\in\mathbb{R}^2,
$$

I have calculated the $(0,t)$-flow ($\Phi^{t,0}$) and the monodromy operator $M=\Phi^{2\pi,0}$.

We have $$\Phi^{t,0}=\Psi(t)=
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{2}e^t(\sin(t)+2) & 0 \\
\frac{1}{2}(e^{t} - \frac{1}{5} e^{t} (\cos t - 2 \sin t) - \frac{4}{5}e^{-t}) & e^{-t}
\end{pmatrix},$$ and therefore $$M=\Phi^{2\pi,0}=
\begin{pmatrix}
e^{2\pi} & 0 \\
\frac{2}{5}(e^{2\pi}-e^{-2\pi}) & e^{-2\pi}
\end{pmatrix},
$$
where $\Psi(t)$ is the fundamental matrix of $A$.

Now the exercise wants me to find a matrix $\Omega$ such that $M=e^{2\pi\Omega}$.

I already know that $\Omega=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\\frac{4}{5} & -1\end{pmatrix}$ (it was given so we'd know when we'd have found the correct answer), but I have to know how to get it, and also how to check that it is true (which I know by using Matlab, but cannot replicate myself).

**This is where I think I have to look:**

By Floquet's theorem I know that there exists a substitution of variables
$$y=\Lambda(t)z(t), t\in\mathbb{R},$$
with $\Lambda:\mathbb{R}\to M_n(\mathbb{C}), \Lambda(t+\tau)=\Lambda(t)$ (with $\tau=2\pi$ in our case?), such that the system at the start of this question becomes the system with constant coefficients:
$$
\frac{dz}{dt}=\Omega z, z\in\mathbb{C}^n, \Omega\in M_n(\mathbb{C}).
$$

But I don't know $\Omega$, $z$, $\Lambda$, and for $y$ I'm also not sure (one of two columns of fundamental matrix?)

I have already found that the eigenvalues of $M$ are $\mu_1=e^{2\pi}$ and $\mu_2=e^{-2\pi}$.

Only in the next step, where I already had to know the answer to this question, do they tell me that $\Lambda(t)=\Phi^{t,0}e^{-t\Omega}$, which they ask me to calculate in this next step. (But that's a question for another post)

Comment: Are you asking about the matrix logarithm, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix , or why exactly $\Psi^{2\pi,0}=e^{2\pi\Omega}$?

Comment: @AVK I am making an exercise that requires me to rewrite $\Phi^{t,0}$ into something of the form $e^{2\pi\Omega}$, where $\Omega\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$. But I have found a solution, for which I will now create an answer.

Answer (score 1):

*After reading on the Jordan canonical form, I discovered an answer myself*

Since $M\in M_2(\mathbb{C})$ has two distinct eigenvalues, we have that $M$ is diagonalizable.
We write
$$M=PJP^{-1},\quad J=\begin{pmatrix}e^{-2\pi} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{2\pi}\end{pmatrix},\quad P\in M_2(\mathbb{C}),\quad\det(P)\neq0.$$
So $J$ is a diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues on its diagonal. To find $P$ we solve the system of equations
$$MP=PJ.$$
Since this system has two equations in four unknowns, we have end up with two degrees of freedom, and therefore we have
$$P_{a,b}=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 5a \\ b & 2a \end{pmatrix},$$
for any $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. We choose $P=P_{1,1}$, and see $\det(P)\neq0$, so $P$ has an inverse given by
$$
P^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{2}{5} & 1 \\ \frac{1}{5} & 0\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Because $J$ is a diagonal matrix we have
$$
J
=
\begin{pmatrix}
e^{-2\pi} & 0 \\
0 & e^{2\pi}
\end{pmatrix}
=
e^{
\begin{pmatrix}
-2\pi & 0 \\
0 & 2\pi
\end{pmatrix}
}
=
e^{
2\pi\hat{J}},\quad \hat{J}=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

So we now have an alternate expression for $M$:
$$
M=PJP^{-1}=Pe^{
2\pi\hat{J}}
P^{-1}
=
e^{2\pi P\hat{J}P^{-1}},
$$

where

$$
P\hat{J}P^{-1}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 5 \\
1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
-\frac{2}{5} & 1\\
\frac{1}{5} & 0
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
\frac{4}{5} & -1
\end{pmatrix}
=
\Omega,
$$
and that is exactly as was to be shown.